# How can I style the buttons like these in my Android application?

Tags: android

I would like to style the buttons in my Android application like this:

[image]

Whats the easiest way to  create the buttons like above?

Currently I simply have a rectangle, here is the xml:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/Main_DownloadCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_button_about_state"
            android:text="txt" >
        </Button>
```

What I need to do now is add the extra small rectangles that are on both sides of the main big rectangle. Meaning add a small_rect_grey and after that small_rect_aqua .. how can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried... anything?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 good point.. I added to the main question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Styling Your Button section:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Style

Mainly borderless and custom background

**button_custom.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:onClick="action"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"  />
```